# Error when converting NSString to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, type-conversion, ios-simulator

I'm trying to convert an 'NSString' into a 'NSDate'. My code was working with iOS 7 this morning, and now not working with the iOS 8 simulator... I install iOS 7 simulators to try to fix this matter, but it doesn't change anything. Here is my code :

```
NSString *query = [components objectAtIndex:i];
NSDateFormatter *newformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[newformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate * testdate = [newformatter dateFromString:query];
NSLog(@"Query : %@   Test date format : %@", query,testdate);
```

The result is :

> Query : 2014-10-11 20:02:50   Test date format : (null)

Whyyyyyy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date formatter is incorrect. You should be using `HH` instead of `hh` since it's a 24-hour time.

```
[newformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

I'd recommend bookmarking [this reference](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: You're agree. My simulator should be in 12-hour time before

Answer (score 0):

What is *query?

I think you are missing the date string, something like this:

```
NSString *dateString = "10-10-2014";
```

And them

```
  NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc]init];
 dateFromString = [newFormatter dateFromString:dateString]; // newFormatter is the format you showed in your example.
```

Comment: He logged `query`, it's clearly the string `2014-10-11 20:02:50`.

Comment: Doesn't look to work.. Query is a NSString. It is correctly filled because you could see in the NSLog that it is correctly printed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the formatter's locale

```
[dateFormatter setLocale: [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]]
```

Also Try turning the am/pm setting on then off.

Comment: If he were to set that locale then the device's 12- or 24-hour clock setting would make no difference.

Comment: Sure. Just wanted him to be sure about both cases.